# Determining the height of a dome given the width and original length.

Tags: trigonometry

I need to determine the height of a dome.  This dome is created by bending an 8 meter pole into shape (refer to image).  I know the width of the dome and the length of the straight arms (also refer to image) once the original pole is bent into shape but i need to determine the height. How would i do this?

Thanks!
[image: Height of Dome]

Comment: The end sections of length 0.14m are vertical, right? So ignore them, and pretend the pole is 7.72m long. Is the curved part a circular arc? That is physically unlikely, but if not, what is its shape? A semi-ellipse?

Comment: To follow up on TonyK's comment, if your shape *is* semi-circular, then the radius of the circle is $7.72m / $pi \approx 2.46m$; if you add to that the $0.14m$ from the straight segments, you get $h = 2.6m$.

Comment: (Reformatted) To follow up on TonyK's comment, if your shape is semi-circular, then the radius of the circle is $7.72\text{m}/\pi \approx 2.46$m; if you add to that the  $0.14$m from the straight segments,you get $h = 2.6$m.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. To follow up TonyK's question, as to my awareness i believe this would be a curved part of a circular arc. To follow up Jon's comment.  This is not a semi circle, it is part of a semicircle. hence the radius wouldn't be 2.46m... This is the part I am stuck at..

Answer (score 1):

A circle drawn along the $x$-axis, intersecting the $y$-axis at $(0,3)$ and $(0,-3)$, with equation

$$(x-a)^2+y^2 = \pi^2,$$ solves the problem.  Using the Pythagorean theorem, $a=\sqrt{\pi^2-9}$.  You can check that $\theta \pi= \frac{8}{\pi}*\pi = 8$.